# Flutter useEffect with Key notices value change only once

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

I've written a code like below and expected the value on screen to never change from "value by useEffect".

*Since every time the button is pressed and the text is changed to "value by onPress", useEffect should catch the change and reset value to "value by useEffect".

However, the useEffect seems to have triggered only when the screen was initialized and first time the button was pressed.

From the second button press, change of text looks to be ignored by useEffect.

How does this happen?

*In other words, how to properly write a "useEffect" which reacts to change of certain property every time?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class PlayHooks extends HookConsumerWidget {
  PlayHooks({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final ephemeralStateText = useState("init value");

    useEffect(() {
      debugPrint("useEffect triggered.");
      ephemeralStateText.value = "value by useEffect";
      return;
    }, [ephemeralStateText.value]);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("play hooks")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: [
          Text("ephemeral state text is ${ephemeralStateText.value}"),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => ephemeralStateText.value = "value by onPress",
              child: Text("change ephemeral state text")),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use curly braces on function shorthand in Dart. The syntax `=> expr` is equal to `{ return expr; }`. Otherwise, the function will return whatever defined by the expression with curly braces (like Map or Set). Notice how this is **different** with Javascript arrow function syntax.

Change this:

```dart
onPressed: () => {ephemeralStateText.value = "value by onPress"}
```

to this:

```
onPressed: () => ephemeralStateText.value = "value by onPress"
```

---

More about function syntax in Dart: https://dart.dev/language/functions

---

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned by the OP, final solution is to remove this line from the callback inside `useEffect`:

```dart
ephemeralStateText.value = "value by useEffect";
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. I've fixed the syntax.
Unfortunately it wasn't enough to solve the issue.

Comment: No. It still shows "value by onPress" after pressing button for the second time (which is not what I expect)

Comment: Well it's a little bit weird that you are changing something in useEffect that is also the key. Maybe make another useState and change the text of that other one instead.

Comment: Ah, that is very true. In fact, removing the line below made it work as I wanted. Thank you!
> ephemeralStateText.value = "value by useEffect";